# Convert a list of dates to date ranges in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a query as following:

```
SELECT  [Date] FROM [TableX] ORDER  BY [Date]
```

The result is:

```
2016-06-01
2016-06-03
2016-06-10
2016-06-11
```

How can I get following pairs?

```
From        To
2016-06-01  2016-06-03
2016-06-03  2016-06-10
2016-06-10  2016-06-11
```

Comment: does your date field always have sequential dates, without missing any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little tricky solution for SQL 2008.

```
declare @tbl table(dt datetime)
insert @tbl values
('2016-06-01'),
('2016-06-03'),
('2016-06-10'),
('2016-06-11')

;with cte as (
select dt, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by dt) rn --add number
from @tbl
),
newTbl as (
select t1.dt start, t2.dt [end]
from cte t1 inner join cte t2 on t1.rn+1=t2.rn
)
select *
from newTbl
```

The result is what you wish.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using SQL Server 2012 or later, you can use the [LEAD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) method.

> Accesses data from a subsequent row in the same result set without the use of a self-join in SQL Server 2016. LEAD provides access to a row at a given physical offset that follows the current row.

I think it would look like this for you:

```
SELECT [Date] AS [From], LEAD([Date], 1) OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) AS [To]
FROM TableX
ORDER BY [Date]
```

Note that on the last row, the [To] field will be `NULL`. If you wanted to remove that row, you could put it in an inner query:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT [Date] AS [From], LEAD([Date], 1) OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) AS [To]
    FROM TableX
) x
WHERE [To] IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is add a row number for each `date`.

Then unite all these rows by the next row (except the last row)

```
WITH cteDates AS
(
    SELECT  [Date],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT [Date])) As RowNum
    FROM    TableX
)

SELECT  TOP(SELECT COUNT(*) - 1 FROM cteDates)
            [Date] [From],
            (SELECT [Date] FROM cteDates WHERE RowNum = d.RowNum + 1) [To]
FROM    cteDates d
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are never any gaps as you stated, you can just used `DATEADD()`

```
 SELECT DISTINCT 
       [Date] as [FROM],
       DATEADD(DAY,1,[Date]) as [TO]
    FROM TableX
    ORDER BY [Date] DESC
```

Comment: It is wrong. it shows 4 rows but it should be 3 rows

Comment: @scsimon sorry, it's actually not sequential. The dates could be different. They are ordered and distinct but not incremental.